# how to preload and display image on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the large amount of similar questions, I wasn't able to really find what I need, despite it seems to be very common...

I have a user profile Form. So the user can upload an avatar. It uses a common 'Browse...' button but this one will inform the server on the next submit.

So I would like to retrieve the local image filename and directory path to immediately display the selected image.

```
<img src="" id="image_to_display" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" role="form" action="/pros/sites/add">
    <input class="form-control"  value="POST" type="hidden" name="_method" id="_method" />
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group file">
               <input type="file" name="logofile" onchange="loadImg('logofile');" id="logofile">
            </div>

         .....
         </fieldset>                            
      .....
 </form>
```

From document.getElementById("logofile"), I can only get the image name, not the pathname.

How to do it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/ here's a great solution. Very straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From document.getElementById("logofile"), I can only get the image name, not the pathname.

That's because you are grabbing the element within the DOM, that element doesn't know about where the file was on the system, it just knows there is a file now that the DOM can look at (where it's at isn't relevant right now).

*You are overcomplicating the problem.*

You don't need to look for the image on the user's system to display it.

Simplify your problem and do something like what others have shown here on stackoverflow.

**The solution:**

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27165977/1026898 does exactly what you want.

1. You will accept the file within the form as you are now.
2. Then you use javascript to detect when the form has been updated with the image by the user.
3. Then you set an image tag's source (An image element that is going to display the 'preview', in your case the element with the id of `image_to_display`.  You set this with `element.src`) to the image that was selected in the form (this is the image itself).

Using your code:

```
<img src="" id="image_to_display" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" role="form" action="/pros/sites/add">
    <input class="form-control"  value="POST" name="_method" id="_method" />
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group file">
               <input type="file" name="logofile" id="logofile" onchange="loadFile(event)">
            </div>

         .....
         </fieldset>                            
      .....
 </form>
 <script>
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('image_to_display');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: That's perfect @Ecnalyr, it seems that the code you give me and which I tested thru the link you gave me, doesn't exactly do what I want as it doesn't immediately display the image but, the second code snippet using FileReader.readAsDataURL() do what I want. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the path name because it's a privacy issue for one thing and you won't be able to assign it to an `<img src` anyway due to cross origin rules. You need to look into using `FileReader` although it requires relatively modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE 10 ...)